# Find and Replace multiple numbers in identical lines in Notepad++

Tags: replace, find, notepad++

Here's an example of what I need to find:

> { n="HOLD", t="INTEGER", v=**number** },

Replace it with:

> { n="HOLD", t="INTEGER", v=**double that number** },

Thank you.

Comment: Regular expressions don't do math, they deal with text.

Comment: You can't do that with regex in Notepad++. You have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: How about a different number then? I just need to change it to something else.